# Не удается вывести массив с необходимыми значениями

Tags: java, массивы

Необходимо составить массив из элементов первого исходного массива, имеющих отличные значения от второго исходного массива. Исходные массивы вводятся с клавиатуры. Но составить 3-й массив никак не выходит. Буду благодарен за помощь

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MyArray1 {
public static void main(String[] args) 
{  
    int [] Mass1;
int [] Mass2;
    int size;
int number;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Укажите размер первого массива: ");
size = in.nextInt();
// Инициализация первого массива
Mass1 = new int[size+1];
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Введите " + i + " элемент массива: ");
        number = in.nextInt();
    Mass1[i] = number;
    }

System.out.print("\nУкажите размер второго массива: ");
size = in.nextInt();
// Инициализация второго массива
Mass2 = new int [size];
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Введите " + i + " элемент массива: ");
        number = in.nextInt();
        Mass2[i] = number;
}

    int[] arrayNew = new int[oneMass.length];  
    int q=0;// Объявление массива разных чисел
    int counterForArrayNew = 0;                     // Счетчик для массива разных чисел
    boolean checkTheSame = false;
    for (i = 0; i < oneMass.length; i++) {        // Начинаем поиск разных элементов основного массива
        for (j = 0; j < twoMass.length; j++) {
            if(oneMass[i] != twoMass[j]) {
                arrayNew[q]=oneMass[i];
                checkTheSame = true;
            }
        }
        if(!checkTheSame) {
            arrayNew[counterForArrayNew++] = oneMass[i]; // Сохраняем найденный элемент в новый массив
        }
        checkTheSame = false;

    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Новый массив:");
    for (i = 0; i < arrayNew.length& arrayNew[i] != 0; i++) {
        System.out.print(arrayNew[i] + ", ");
    }
```

Comment: Логика неверна. Следует искать не пары неравных и оставлять, а пары равных и отбрасывать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проще готовыми средствами обработать массивы:

```
static List<Integer> getList(int[] array) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i : array) {
        list.add(i);
    }
    return list;
}

...

// Для удобства, уже имеем заполненные массивы
int[] array1 = {1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8};
int[] array2 = {1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 0};

// Массивы превращаем в списки
List<Integer> list1 = getList(array1);
List<Integer> list2 = getList(array2);

// Удаление элементов из list1, что есть в list2
list1.removeAll(list2);
System.out.println(list1);  // [3, 6, 7, 8]
```